# Let $X$ be compact, let $p: X \to Y$ be the quotient map, if $p$ is a closed map, then Y is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I wonder if anyone could give me a hint, What I've done is let $x,y \in Y$, since $p$ is surjective, we have $x',y' \in X$ such that $p(x') = x $ and $p(y') = y$ but I don't know how to continue, since the singletons of $X$ are non necessarily closed. Any hint is appreciated

Comment: What's the precise statement? If $X$ is allowed to be non-Hausdorff, then can $g$ be the identity map, which is surjective and closed?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: $X$ has to be assumed Hausdorff, otherwise it is false. For the solution in Hausdorff case see this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+projections+out+of+compact+Hausdorff+spaces+are+closed+precisely+if+the+codomain+is+Hausdorff